# computeDistance не хочет считать, в компилировании отказывает. Ткните носом, как переписать ...?

Tags: java, android, yandex-maps-api

```
String StartEnd = jsonPropose.getString("addr");
        String[] massAdr = StartEnd.split(",");
        Log.e("<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______1:" +massAdr[0] +massAdr[1]);
        Log.e("<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______2:" +massAdr[2]+massAdr[3]);
        String SummStart = addPrefix+massAdr[0]+massAdr[1];
        String SummEnd = addPrefix+massAdr[2]+massAdr[3];
/////Тут ОСТАПА ПОНЕСЛО...
        URL url1 = new URL(yandexApiUrl + (SummStart));
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.connect();
        char[] buff = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer sbJson1 = new StringBuffer();
        JSONObject jsonResponse1 = new JSONObject(sbJson1.toString());
        String StartPoint = jsonResponse1.getJSONObject("response").
               getString("pos");
        String[] latLon1 = StartPoint.split(" ");


        URL url2 = new URL(yandexApiUrl + (SummEnd));
        StringBuffer sbJson2 = new StringBuffer();
        JSONObject jsonResponse2 = new JSONObject(sbJson2.toString());
        String EndPoint = jsonResponse2.getJSONObject("response").
                getString("pos");
        String[] latLon2 = EndPoint.split(" ");

       double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween (latLon1,latLon2);

        if (distance<=prefs.getMaxAllowedDistance()) {
            boolean shouldConfirm = true;
            Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
            else {
            Log.e("FUCK !");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween принимает на вход LatLng, а у вас в параметрах массивы стрингов. Вам иде прямым текстом должно говорить, "exepted LatLng, found String[]". Будьте внимательнее. И приведите к нужному типу параметры

```
LatLng from = new LatLng(Doouble.parse(latLon1[0]),Doouble.parse(latLon1[1]))
LatLng to = new LatLng(Doouble.parse(latLon2[0]),Doouble.parse(latLon2[1]))
double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween (from,to);
```